# HAproxy-reverse proxy for multiple domains - 503 service unavailable

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have try to setup a HAproxy - reverse proxy for multiple domains.But when i tried the HAProxy url in browser, it shows "503 - service unavailable".

Am trying to setup this,I have four domains- when any one hits the proxy server url ,the request has to go the particular domain belongs to the request.

Below my haproxy config file.

```
log         127.0.0.1 local2
chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
maxconn     4000
user        haproxy
group       haproxy
daemon

# turn on stats unix socket
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
```

---

defaults

```
mode                    http
log                     global
option                  httplog
option                  dontlognull
option                  http-server-close
option                  forwardfor
option                  redispatch
retries                 3
timeout http-request    10s
timeout queue           1m
timeout connect         10s
timeout client          1m
timeout server          1m
timeout http-keep-alive 10s
timeout check           10s
maxconn                 3000
```

---

frontend   http-in
bind *:80

```
    acl host1 hdr(host) -i xyz.com
    acl host2 hdr(host) -i abc.com
    acl host3 hdr(host) -i ghy.com
    acl host4 hdr(host) -i klm.com

    use_backend xyz if host1
    use_backend abc if host2
    use_backend ghy if host3
    use_backend klm if host4
```

---

backend xyz

```
    mode    http
    balance     roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server s2 xyz.com:80 check
```

backend abc

```
    mode    http
    balance     roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server s1 abc.com:80 check
```

backend ghy

```
    mode    http
    balance     roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server s4 ghy.com:80 check
```

backend klm

```
    mode    http
    balance     roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server s3 klm.com:443 check
```

listen webinterface

bind 0.0.0.0:9200

mode http

stats enable

stats uri /

stats realm Strictly\ Private

stats auth admin:admin@123

---

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Read your logs, please.  Every request is logged with a 4-character code describing the state of the session when the request finished processing.  For successful requests, it's typically `----`.  Otherwise, the codes are documented.

Comment: I am getting the log like this below in haproxy,      Jun 23 21:37:40 localhost haproxy[3344]: 192.168.4.28:20346 [23/Jun/2016:21:37:40.384] http-in http-in/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 503 212 - - SC-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "POST http://example.com HTTP/1.1"   : Note :  example.com is abc.com

Comment: HAProxy balancer and backends in sames subnetworks?

Answer (score 3):

Getting `503 - service unavailable` from haproxy indicates that the backend server is not serving requests properly - if you check your stats page (e.g. `http://localhost:9200/`), the server will be shown in red (if the server were healthy, it would be shown in green; a healthy backup server would be shown in blue).

Since your `server` lines include the [check](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#check) keyword, haproxy is periodically polling each backend server to see if the server is "healthy" - that is, if it returns a 2xx-3xx HTTP status (for [http checks](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#option%20httpchk)).

You have several options:

- Remove `check` from your `server` lines - haproxy assumes the servers are available by default.
- Leave `check` on your `server` lines but configure the `httpchk` (this can be done for each backend). For example: 

  `option forwardfor
  option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent:\ HAProxy\r\nHost:\
  server s2 xyz.com:80 check`

Do not forget to reload/restart haproxy after making config changes!

Comment: Thanks Matt. I will check it.